# "Cannot set property color of #<CLI> which has only a getter" when running sfdx commands

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm getting the following error when running any `sfdx` command with the latest version of the Salesforce CLI on macOS High Sierra:

```
Cannot set property color of #<CLI> which has only a getter
```

I've attempted updating and re-installing the Salesforce CLI but the error persists. No other output results from running any sfdx command other than the error message.

What could be causing this and how might it be resolved?

Comment: This is happening to me as well so maybe its a salesforce issue? I have been working all day and it just started

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We had an auto release with a bug. We've rolled it back. Please run `sfdx update` and ignore the one time error you receive.

The team is already performing a retro to understand how this got out.

Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I didn't do any updates recently and still was getting that issue. Anyways `sfdx update` fixed the issue

Comment: ...and the quick answer!

Comment: The CLI auto-updates itself. I believe you can disable this with `export SFDX_AUTOUPDATE_DISABLE=true` still, but be mindful of what you're missing out on.